# How to mock a Unirest chaining method?

Tags: java, junit, powermock, powermockito, unirest

I have a class like this which uses Unirest API to make a HTTP POST call -

```
public class MyClass{
    public MyObject getData(){
    HttpResponse response = Unirest.post(someURL).header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                        .field("Field1", context.getParameter("value for field 1"))
                        .field("username", context.getParameter("username"))
                        .field("password", context.getParameter("password"))
                        .field("field 3", context.getParameter("field 3 value"))
                        .field("field 4", context.getParameter("field 4 value"))
                        .asJson();
    }
    }
```

In my mock class -
I have a HttpResponse object in my mockito to be returned when Unirest HTTP post would be called.
I don't want to hit the endpoint via Unirest and want to return my custom httpResponse.

```
HttpResonse<JsonNode> httpResponse; // my mocked response
Mockito.when(Unirest.post(someURL).header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                            .field("Field1", context.getParameter("value for field 1"))
                            .field("username", context.getParameter("username"))
                            .field("password", context.getParameter("password"))
                            .field("field 3", context.getParameter("field 3 value"))
                            .field("field 4", context.getParameter("field 4 value"))
                            .asJson()).thenReturn(httpResponse); // this is my custom response
```

I have mocked the context for all params already but still getting error as

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue:
>
> HttpResponse cannot be returned by getParameter()
>
> getParameter() should return String

Is there a way to mock this more easily for 3rd party chaining methods or better example for implementation?
Thanks!

Comment: can you refactor your production code?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, if you are allowed to refactor your code is to extract the static call to a protected method:

```
public class MyClass{
    public MyObject getData(){
      HttpResponse response = postRequest();
    }

    protected HttpResponse postRequest(){
       return Unirest.post(someURL).header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                        .field("Field1", context.getParameter("value for field 1"))
                        .field("username", context.getParameter("username"))
                        .field("password", context.getParameter("password"))
                        .field("field 3", context.getParameter("field 3 value"))
                        .field("field 4", context.getParameter("field 4 value"))
                        .asJson();
    }
}
```

Then in your test case, spy on the class under test and mock the protected method:

```
public void test(){
   MyClass myClass = Mockito.spy(new MyClass());

   HttpResonse<JsonNode> httpResponse; // my mocked response

   doReturn(httpResponse).when(myClass).postRequest();

   ...
}
```

Comment: This would have worked if the Unirest call would have been in postRequest() method. I have a direct call via Unirest.post() which sets the HttpResponse. Is there a way to do that too?

Comment: have you mocked the context object?

Comment: Yes. I have mocked the context object. The problem I see that .field() returns MultipartBody which I have also mocked, but still getting NPE.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of NPE by mocking each multipart request separately. For example :

```
@PrepareForTest({ Unirest.class})
public TestClass {
    @Mock
    private HttpRequestWithBody httpRequestWithBody;

@Test
public void testMethod() {
.
.
.
 httpRequestWithBody = Mockito.mock(HttpRequestWithBody.class);
        MultipartBody multipartUsernameBody = Mockito.mock(MultipartBody.class);
        Mockito.when(httpRequestWithBody.field("username", "username@userdomain.com")).thenReturn(multipartUsernameBody);

        MultipartBody multipartPasswordBody = Mockito.mock(MultipartBody.class);
        Mockito.when(multipartUsernameBody.field("password", "Password123")).thenReturn(multipartPasswordBody);
.
.
.
}
```

Also you have to split your request in the actual code accordingly.